# Do the I/O parallelism truly gives so much perfomance?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, asynchronous, io

There are a lot of questions on stackoverflow: How much threads for IO should I use?
And the answer is one, if CPU isn't buisy, or you will have overhead.

I tested I found that this isn't true at all or maybe my test code is wrong. Lets try just
copy big files sync and async using .NET:

```
class Program
{
    const string UserDirectory = @"C:\testDir\";
    const string sourceFile1 = UserDirectory + "1.rar";
    const string sourceFile2 = UserDirectory + "2.rar";
    const string dstFile1 = UserDirectory + "1copy.rar";
    const string dstFile2 = UserDirectory + "2copy.rar";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Clear();

        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        StdCopySync();
        Console.WriteLine("Standart copy Sync complited in {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Clear();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        watch.Restart();

        StdCopyAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Standart copy Async complited in {0} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    private static void Clear()
    {
        File.Delete(dstFile1);
        File.Delete(dstFile2);
    }


    private static void StdCopySync()
    {
        File.Copy(sourceFile1, dstFile1);
        File.Copy(sourceFile2, dstFile2);
    }

    private static void StdCopyAsync()
    {

        Task t1 = new Task(() =>
        {
            File.Copy(sourceFile1, dstFile1);
        });

        Task t2 = new Task(() =>
        {
            File.Copy(sourceFile2, dstFile2);
        });

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        Task.WaitAll(new List<Task>() { t1, t2 }.ToArray());
    }
}
```

The average results suprized me a lot. (5 mesurements, sourceFile1 is the same as sourceFile2 and size is near 1GB)

- Single HDD, Windows 7: Async is faster on 16%
- SSD, Windows 8: Async is faster on 5%
- RAID 0, Windows 8: Async is faster on 40%. (But why so much? why the controller and kernel isn't paralelize work as expected?)

I also tried do not use standart File. Copy and just write text to files usync .NET Async constructs - the same result.

So I make a conclusion that optimal concarancy level should searching by adaptive alghorithm. And 2 simultaneous IO requests are always better then 1. Do you agree with this?

Comment: Note that async has nothing to do with threads.

Comment: @SLaks Yes, thanks. I mean simultaneous IO requests. Corrected.

Comment: When doing IO, what you need to do is keep the disk hardware busy reading / writing. Threads don't help that.

Comment: I doubt your measurement. Everyone who has tried to copy multiple big files in Windows explorer simultaneously knows that this is not so. We need to find what's wrong with your measurement or special about your setup.

Comment: These tests are notoriously unreliable and don't test I/O speed at all.  Just memory bus bandwidth, used by the file system cache.  Very fast, just a memory-to-memory copy.  Use SysInternals' RAMMap utility to flush the cache first before each test run.  And be sure to test using only a single thread, using more than one is *very* detrimental to speeds when the threads start fighting over the disk and force it to zip back-and-forth.  Albeit that the file copy engine in Windows tries to do something about it, the version matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run multiple sequential IO streams on one magnetic disk you get random IO. Performance totally tanks.

Why is that not the case here? I suspect that your files are small enough to fit into memory/cache. All your work is CPU bound. Even writes are flushed lazily to disk.

You have 4 files of 1GB each. You machine probably has >4GB of RAM.

Increase the file size by 10x and performance will totally tank. You will hear your disk rattling madly from all the disk seeks.

Using Process Monitor you can see that Windows (very unfortunately) issues 256KB IOs to the underlying disks interleaved. That is far to small to realize sequential performance.

I repeat my comment here:

> I doubt your measurement. Everyone who has tried to copy multiple big files in Windows explorer simultaneously knows that this is not so. We need to find what's wrong with your measurement or special about your setup.

In other words, your benchmark is not measuring what you think it is.

Answer (score 2):

IO operations are going to be IO bound, not CPU bound.  CPU operations are going to be CPU bound.

For IO operations you *shouldn't* have the CPU maxed out on resources.  If you do, you don't have an IO bound operation, you have a CPU bound operation.

IO operations, if they are exposed through properly asynchronous APIs, don't need *any threads*.  [There is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).  If you only have synchronous APIs, then you need as many threads as it takes to keep whatever IO medium at full capacity.  That could be one thread, two, or hundreds.

Once you're to the point where you have close to 100% utilization of the IO based resource (whether that be a hard disk, a database, a network connection, etc.) adding additional threads doesn't help.  In fact, it can sometimes even hurt.  For example, hard disks are heavily optimized for sequential access.  Parallelizing often results in more random access, which can actually result in dramatically lower performance.

Answer (score 0):

Async is much faster on RAID because it exploits more device parallelism. Only for very fast PCI-E based SSD's will more I/O threads gets you much higher performance numbers (to saturate the PCI bandwidth). For most things having better I/O depth (issue bigger I/O's really) will get you better performance.